# Weird 6th grade problem from plane geometry :(

Tags: geometry, triangles

I stumbled upon a problem in 6th grade geometry book.

The problem is as follows:

$AD\cong EC$ and $\angle ECD\cong \angle DAE$. We have to prove that $AB\cong BC$.

I stuck since we can not use angle sum in this problem.

Only things we can use, as I see, are Side-Angle-Side condition, Angle-Side-Angle condition or Side-Side-Side condition. Obviously we also can use properties of isosceles triangle which follows from the three conditions.

Does anyone see how to approach this problem?

[image: Figure]

Comment: To be clear: Is the Angle-Angle-Side (AAS) congruence pattern disallowed?

Comment: @Blue Sure I guess we can use AAS too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AAS to prove the congruence of the bottom triangles.  Then connect $\overline{AC}$ and use the properties of an isosceles triangle to prove the base angles $\angle EAC$ and $\angle ACD$ are congruent.  In particular, the base angles of $\triangle ABC$ are congruent, and so it's isosceles too.

Comment: Do you use equality of vertical angles here? If not I can not see your point in your first sentence.

Comment: I looked in the book once more there is no theorem about equality of vertical angles there before this problem, but nevertheless we surely can prove it without any difficult tools. Your answer is acceptable for me but it is very strange for me that this problem is asked there in such a manner.

Comment: Well yeah I'm definitely using vertical angles congruence. All advanced math proofs use basic human intuition. I see no reason why 6th grade geometry shouldn't do the same.

Comment: :D Intuition lies sometimes. Well I tried to figure out rigorous inference and stuck. The problem is that ththis one is taken from Kolmogorov, Semenovich, Nagibin, Cherkasov text book for 6th grade scool children and the textbook rely on Euclid-like axiomatic method.

Comment: Where do you think the axioms came from?